# How to smooth plots with different x-coordinates in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot runs of an algorithm over time with ggplot, but I want to smooth them in one line and add these nice ribbons. Like here (lattice and ggplot2 from the ggplot manual, I couldn' t find the code):
[image]

BUT! I have 100 runs all consisting of 1000 datapoints or so. The problem is that these datapoints all have different x-coordinates. So I think the average cannot be computed well to get this smooth line? Is that true?

If so, I would want to draw 100 smoothed lines, and sample them at fixed intervals (say every at x=100, x=200 etc) and then produce and average smooth line with these ribbons (that show variance or 90% interval or so).

Once I have the data sampled at the fixed x-coordinates, I could do something like this:

```
data
months <- c(1:12)
 High <- c(-6,-2,5,14,21,26,28,27,22,14,4,-3)
Low <- c(-16,-11,-5,2,9,14,17,16,11,4,-4,-12)
Mean <- c(-11,-7,0,8,15,20,23,22,16,9,1,-7)
Prepmm <- c(26.4 ,20.1 ,47.2 ,58.7 ,82.3 ,110.2 ,102.6 ,102.9 ,68.3 ,53.6 ,49.3 ,25.4 )
Prep <- Prepmm * 0.1 # converting to cm
minptemp <- data.frame(months, High, Low, Mean, Prep)



# plot
require(ggplot2)  # need to install ggplot2 
plt <- ggplot(minptemp, aes(x= months))
plt + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin= Low, ymax= High), fill="yellow") + geom_line(aes(y=Mean))+
geom_point(aes(x = months, y = Prep)) + theme_bw( ) # ribbon plus point plot months
```

To get: 
[image]

How do I sample the 100 smoothed lines? Is that even possible? Or is there another way?

My data looks something like this:

```
run 1
x  y
1  100
4  90
7  85
10 80

run 2
x  y
1  150
2  85
10 60
```

etc for 100 runs...

so not complete as you can see:

```
x1; y1  ; x2 ; y3
1 ; 100 ; 1  ; 150
4 ; 90  ; 2  ; 85
7 ; 85  ; 10 ; 60
10; 80  ;
```

If it takes the average at say x = 4, will it take into account that the value for the second run would be between 85 and 60?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to preprocess the data with R first:

```
xx <- read.table(text='x1; y1  ; x2 ; y2
1 ; 100 ; 1  ; 150
4 ; 90  ; 2  ; 85
7 ; 85  ; 10 ; 60
10; 80  ;',sep=';',fill=TRUE,header=TRUE)

dm <- merge(xx[,1:2],xx[,3:4],by=1,all=T)
dm <- dm[!is.na(dm$x1),]
dm$y1 <- zoo::na.locf(dm$y1)
dm$y2 <- zoo::na.locf(dm$y2)
dm
  x1  y1  y2
1  1 100 150
2  2 100  85
3  4  90  85
4  7  85  85
5 10  80  60
```